# python post request with certificate

Tags: python, python-requests

how to send certificate authentication in python post request,
for example I used next but in get request: 
requests.get(url, params = params, timeout=60,cert=certs)
where certs is path to certificate,
it's worked fine.
requests.post(url_post,data=params,cert = certs, timeout=60)
not working, error - SSL authentication error

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: requests.post(url_post,data=params,cert = certs, timeout=60)

Answer (score 2):

To send certificate, you need the certificate which contains public key like server.crt. If you have this crt file then you can send it as

> `r=requests.get('https://server.com', verify='server.crt' )`

or if you don't have that file then you can get it using get_ssl_certificate method

> ert=ssl.get_server_certificate(('server.com',443),ssl_version=3)

then you can write it into a file and send it.